# What's the correct way to create a node ? and can anyone explain for me the createNode parameter

Tags: alfresco

I'm working on alfresco 3.4, and i'm trying to create a node and i have a problem after node creation modeled in a node browser that cannot see my new nodes, so

Can anyone help me and see me how to create a node and what are the create node method parameters ? can any one guide me and clarify the create node method.

Thanks
Mohammed Amr
Senior System Developer
Digital Series

Comment: How are you creating your nodes? The JavaScript API? The Java NodeService? Java FileFolderService? Posting JSON to a built in webscript?

Comment: i create my node either using Calling create node upon Java "NodeService" or using built-in functionality of alfresco itself by choose create content action.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

EDIT: just [checked](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Data_Dictionary_Guide#Child_Associations), use ASSOC_CONTAINS instead of ASSOC_CHILDREN

There are different ways to create new content from your Java code, like using:

- [FileFolderService.create](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/service/cmr/model/FileFolderService.html#create(org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.NodeRef,%20java.lang.String,%20org.alfresco.service.namespace.QName,%20org.alfresco.service.namespace.QName))
- [NodeService.createNode](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/service/cmr/repository/NodeService.html#createNode(org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.NodeRef,%20org.alfresco.service.namespace.QName,%20org.alfresco.service.namespace.QName,%20org.alfresco.service.namespace.QName))

I assume you're referring here to the latter method. Let's see the method signature (there's another version of `createNode` that also accepts a `Map` for the initial properties, I'd just skip it for now):

```
ChildAssociationRef createNode(NodeRef parentRef,
                               QName assocTypeQName,
                               QName assocQName,
                               QName nodeTypeQName)
                               throws InvalidNodeRefException,
                                      InvalidTypeException
```

Let's say we want to create a new node under a folder, your code will look like the following:

```
NodeRef folderNode = getMyFolderNode();
ChildAssociationRef childAssoc = nodeService.createNode(folderNode,
                                             ContentModel.ASSOC_CONTAINS,
                                             QName.createQName("{foo}bar"),
                                             ContentModel.TYPE_CONTENT);
```

The result of this call will be a new node being created under **`folderNode`**.

The new node will be bound to its parent folder by an association of type **`ContentModel.ASSOC_CONTAINS`**: this is the most critical part, as nodes can be related using a number of different associations, but the parent-child one that the node browser uses to display content as being filed one within the other is only this one.

**`{foo}bar`** is a `QName` that identifies this specific parent-child association itself. In the node browser, you can see the effect of this parameter in the node path, like `/app:company_home/...../foo:bar`.

The last **`ContentModel.TYPE_CONTENT`** parameter is, of course, the type you want to create the new node with. You might want to use a `QName` that refers to some custom type of yours.

Comment: I get it, so when i create a node i need to bind the namespace uri rather than prefix only and if i use the prefix them i need to pass an instance of nameSpaceResolver to resolve the prefix with its uri and once i need to search about the created node via the node browser it's a must to use the namespace uri such as           TYPE:"{www.ds.alfresco.security.extension.com}organization" to find the created node but when i use TYPE:"sec:organization" the node will not be found. so as conclusion i must use the namespaceResolver to bind prefix with its uri and use it as a keyword in the browser

Comment: using Node Browser, when i search bu using sec:organization the result is zero but when i use {myURI}organization the nodes are returned.

Comment: double check `myURI` is **absolutely identical** to the one specified in your custom model `namespace uri="...."`. For instance, all the initial `http://..` characters, if you have them, are required.

Comment: My URI is identical to www.ds.alfresco.security.extension.com, and by using it to search on the node browser the nodes will be returned and by using the prefix sec the result is zero. so you can consider two types of search keywords TYPE:"sec:organization" with no result and TYPE:"{MYURI}organization" with results returned using lucene search.

Comment: But, Why when i shutdown the alfresco and startup it again and search using the URI or prefix the result is zero ?

Comment: that sounds to me more like there's something going on with your content, e.g. it gets deleted or something. Searching using short prefixes or long URIs is absolutely identical, as you already discovered that they are eventually the same thing, minus the prefix resolver that translates prefixes into long URIs.

Comment: The nodes are not deleted, simply they are not searched once i shutdown and startup the server again ! but if i navigate to the folder where the nodes are placed there.

Comment: may be i need to use namespaceService.registerNamesapce(prefix,uri) !

Comment: Skuro, i tried to create the content using the create content built-in functionality provided by alfresco. I made a shutdown and other startup twice in the first the node browser finds the nodes and in the other it is not find them !